# MySQL PHP PDO : getting the table AND its size from a request

Tags: php, mysql

I have several functions in a PHP script :

```
    // Database connexion
    function connexion_base() 
    {
        try
        {
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=WORLD',
                       'me','S3cr3T');
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
        }
        return $bdd;
    }

    // Returns the names of the columns
    function column_names($Table) 
    {
        $nb_cols = $Table->columnCount();
        $cols = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nb_cols; $i++)
        {
            $col = $Table->getColumnMeta($i);
            $cols[] = $col['name'];
        }
        return $cols;
    }

    // Prints the body of the table
    function print_table($Table,$Cols) 
    {
        while ($datas = $Table->fetch()) 
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($Cols as $element)
            {
                echo '<td>'.$datas[$element].'</td>';
            }
        }
    }

    // Prints the result of request $Request (string) from database $Bdd
    function print_request($Base,$Request)
    {
        $result = $Bdd->query($Requete);
        $cols = column_names($resultat);
        // Printing numer of rows of the result
        // echo '<p>Number of lines in the answer : '.$nb_lignes.'</p>';
        // Head of the table
        echo '<table> <tr>';
        foreach ($cols as $element)
        {
            echo '<th>'.$element.'</th>';
        }
        // End head of the table
        // Printing each line of the table
        write_table($result,$cols);
        // Fin de la table
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
```

Problem(s) is(are) :

1. is my code correct ? It works, but maybe I didn't get the correct feeling about working with PDO (and/or PHP, MySQL...)
2. i'd like to add a line in the resulting page, before the table, indicating the number of results given by the request; and I don't know how to do it.

Any help ?

Comment: Is this code used to create a table from any mysql query result?

It is also unclear to me how you created $Bdd, especially the type or logic to create the object would be helpful

Comment: Hi @avdg. I added some code to explain what $Bdd is. And yes, the intention of this function "print_request" is to print the resulting table of ANY request in the database.

Answer (score 0):

To add a line you can do `<tr><td colspan="{$nb_cols}">{$result->rowCount()}</td></tr>` after the `th` or after the `write_table`

Please watch the typos in your variables (`$resultat -> $result`), so that they are all the same. Php isn't case sensitive, but I would recommended to not rely on that to avoid consufusion by not mixing same variable names but with different styles.

Picky notes: please output `</tr>` after each loop, even though browsers are being able to find their way out

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved my problem in a different way, not very efficient, but it worls. For the typos, I translated my code from french, sorry if I missed one or two translations.
And thank you for pointing the absence of the </tr> tags. Missed that one :-)